# C++ repeated indirect vs direct access

Tags: c++, performance, game-engine

This is a rather pedantic question, but I want to get the most performance out of my game. This game includes accessing an array of a data structure, but I dont know the size of this array (e.g. players or items etc. you can imagine). It's a dynamic pool of memory. I have the choice to do this use an array dynamically allocated, which works for run time. Now I added a map editor into the game which must be able to resize these arrays as you add/remove entities. I then wrote an array to pointers of that data structure, so you can allocate one by one and remove one by one. But accessing an variable from an array of pointers to that variable vs accessing a variable in an array, I presume the last one if faster. I can impossibly allocate a fixed size array at the beginning, that would eat the memory away (the game could become large) and be a waste. Which option should I choose for the best speed (runtime)? This decision is very important: either I split the editor and gamerun variables (an array to pointers vs a pointer) (causing a bigger application, maploading functions are based on these variables) or I use the same variable (an array of pointers) for both modes. I preferably have the last one, but I am afraid that it will take away a lot of performance. What should I choose?

Comment: Use `std::vector<>`, not arrays.

Comment: _'but I am afraid that it will take away a lot of performance'_ don't be afraid, **measure** instead.

Comment: Whether your question is pedantic I won't answer, but the wall of text is annoying. Please edit and insert some whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

I can't exactly what you are tying to do. However, many processors (e.g. Intel Pentium) have indexed addressing modes with multiple registers.

The difference between accessing an array of objects and array of pointers is likely to be zero to one instructions.

Write a small sample using each method. Compile and generate an assembly listing.

Repetition is what tends to cause the most degradation in performance; not coding techniques.